# Setting a SPARQL Variable to a value based on value of another variable

Tags: sparql

I am trying to do something in SPARQL which I suspect may not be possible, but I wanted to ask the community to see anyway.

Let's assume a mini-database populated with just the following RDF triples:

```
:a :b :c
:d :b :e
:f :b :g
```

A SPARQL `INSERT` statement is run against the database:

```
INSERT {
    ?subject :h ?var .
    ?var a :type1 .
}
WHERE {
    ?subject :b ?object .
}
```

This `INSERT` statement will not work, because the variable `?var` is unbound. I am looking for a way to set the value of this variable **as something different for each value** of variable `?subject`, ideally a `UUID`.

I would like my `INSERT` statement to add triples like this to the database:

```
:a :h :123abc
:123abc a type1
:d :h :456cde
:456cde a type1
:f :h :789def
:789def :a type1
```

Some additional thoughts:

- The value of `?var` has to remain bound for each graph pattern with a unique value of `?subject` because there are multiple triples to be inserted which need to use the same value (in this case, setting the type as `type1` and the relationship with `?subject`)
- Using a `BIND` clause in the `WHERE` block will probably not work because that will create a static value for `?var` which applies to the entire graph pattern, regardless of the value of `?subject`

Comment: Use `CONSTRUCT` to build your triples; then wrap that in an `INSERT`. Use a function/expression to generate the UUIDs within the `CONSTRUCT`.

Comment: I've never heard of being able to use a CONSTRUCT within an INSERT...can you post a minimal example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BIND (UUID() AS ?var)` in the `WHERE` clause.

`UUID` generates a new, unique UUID for each call during execution.

In the query example, you can also use a blank node.

`INSERT {
    ?subject :h [ a :type1 ].
} WHERE`

which will have a fresh blank node for each time the template is instantiated, i.e. each row from the WHERE clause.

There is also `BNODE()` which does the same thing - new blank node for each solution row it is called in.

The `WHERE` can also include sub-SELECTs, including assignment.